# ActiveRecord dependency with Ruby, Rails, Cucumber, & RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, webrat

We are writing a Rails application that is using CouchDB as its data store.  We're BDD/TDD'ing with RSpec and Cucumber, which is using WebRat for webpage testing

I'm trying to remove ActiveRecord as one of the resources that is being loaded by rails but its causing the cucumber tests to fail.  I've removed all references that I can find (fixtures, environment files, etc...) but it still fails without it.

Has anyone seen this?  The application runs fine without, but the test don't.

**edit**

I did remove the framework in env file, I also removed all the transactional fixture code.  We're using the latest version of rspec and rspec-rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First stab at the problem.**
Really I need a little more information, but...

Assuming you have done this in config/environment.rb:

```
  # Skip frameworks you're not going to use. To use Rails without a database
  # you must remove the Active Record framework.
  config.frameworks -= [ :active_record ]
```

and are using rspec-rails 1.2.6, you would be getting an error like `uninitialized constant Spec::Matchers::Change::ActiveRecord`
which was brought up in [ticket #810](https://rspec.lighthouseapp.com/projects/5645-rspec/tickets/810-specs-fail-if-activerecord-disabled). It was fixed for 1.2.7, which was released only two weeks ago.

If that turns out not to be your problem, could you post the errors you've been getting and maybe some more information about your test environment?